# Php reading object variable as part of other variable

Tags: php, object, var, composition, evaluate

I have an array structure of 60 elements. I'd like to use a for/foreach/while to read this structure.

This is what I have :

```
$this->details->field_link_01[0]['title']
$this->details->field_link_02[0]['title']
..
$this->details->field_link_60[0]['title']
```

And what i need is the following.

```
$myvar = eval ( "$this->details->field_link_" . $cont . "[0]['title']" )
```

What I have seen is PHP let to use $ as evaluation function

```
$myvar = ${"this->details->field_link_" . $cont . "[0]['title']" }
```

But it didn't work.

Is there any other solution ? Which PHP version ? 5.2 , 5.6 , 7 ?

Comment: try

$this->details->field_link_{$count}[0]['title']

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) and [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 60; $i++) {
    $fieldName = sprintf("field_link_%02d", $i);
    $fieldLink = $this->details->$fieldName;

    $myvar = $fieldLink[0]['title'];

    echo $myvar;
}
```