# Php generating dynamic names for functions composed by strings

Tags: php, function, dynamic

I have another idea to improve my code. I want to generate a common call to my functions without neede to repeat all.

This question is related with this one :

[Php reading object variable as part of other variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42649752/php-reading-object-variable-as-part-of-other-variable)

This is my code:

```
function link_01() {}
function link_02() {}
..
function link_0N() {}
```

What I cant to do is the following :

```
$link_name = 'link_0'                                            ;

for($cont=1 ; $cont <= $this->num_links; $cont++)
{
    $linkName                   = sprintf($link_name , $cont)     ; 
    $fieldLink                 = $this->$linkName               ;       
    $fieldLink($cont)                                              ;    
}
```

This don't work. What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

If you use sprinf you need to use a type specifier (http://php.net/manual/ro/function.sprintf.php)

```
$link_name = 'link_0%d'                                            ;

for($cont=1 ; $cont <= $this->num_links; $cont++)
{
    $linkName                   = sprintf($link_name , $cont)     ; 
    $fieldLink                 = $this->$linkName               ;       
    $fieldLink($cont)                                              ;    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try **call_user_func**

Here is document:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php